# Was Uatu ever reinstated as a Watcher?

Tags: marvel

According to [Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/uatu-the-watcher), Uatu was:

> Eventually reinstated into the Watchers

at some point after his expulsion. Did this actually happen in the comics?
The page seems to be years out of date (not updated since Civil War I), and contains this disclaimer in the side well/ rail:

> Take note, True Believer! This crowd-sourced content has not yet been
>   verified for accuracy by our erudite editors!

Comment: It's either a copy paste from the [wiki page](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uatu_(Earth-616)) or the other way around. The wiki cites the paragraph to _Galactus the Devourer_ #1-6 and _Fantastic Four Annual_ #2001. The annual does have Uatu appears and he is called Uatu the Watcher in it so that appears to be as good as we have. No idea if it means he was reinstated or not though because it is Earth heroes calling him that.

Comment: I did notice that. I'm kind of hoping that someone here has access to Galactus the Devourer or another comic that can answer this question. If I don't get any supported "yes" answers, then I will accept a "no" answer. I can update my question to reflect that.

Comment: Galactus the Destroyer is available online through... sources, but the wiki pages don't mention Uatu appears in it so I haven't flipped through yet.